# Selenium chromedriver sees the new version of Google Chrome as the old one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Okay, I uninstalled google chrome with

```
apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

Then I ran the code with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') # tried with 9223 9230 4444
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'

ddriver = Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

Okay, now I install chrome with this:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It saying that google chrome 102.0.5005.61-1 installed, checking:

```
google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61
```

Then `apt update` and `apt upgrade`

Now I launch code again and see this:

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/102.0.5005.61/chromedriver] found in cache
```

And then this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.54 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

I can't understand why is it seeing wrong version of chrome?

Comment: Can you run `which google-chrome-stable` and check that the one it finds is the same as `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` ?

Comment: `which google-chrome-stable`
`/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

Yes, same

Comment: Hi Kevin.  I have seen this before in my own solution (C#).  For me, the project XML was referencing the old AND new version (I had just installed).  When I would try to run, I got basically the same error.  The fix was to search the entire solution and find references to that old driver, in your case:  95.0.4638.54, and remove them.  Once I did that, all worked as expected.

Comment: Sounds like what I need, but I don't have any XML files or other configs where I can find bindings to Google Chrome versions...

Comment: try running Chrome and checking the version.  It's possible that it's checking some kind of ini file instead of the executable.  The first run might update that.

Comment: Didn't help, launched Chrome, checked About, version is 102, but script still sees it like 95